# Using the JDBC getGeneratedKeys function in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc, auto-increment

I have an web application that uses the `AUTO INCREMENT` value of one table to insert into other tables. I need to ensure that the value read for the Auto Increment column is correct in the presence of potential concurrent `INSERT`s into that table. Since each thread will have its own connection (from the container pool) do I still have to put the code within a transaction?

```java
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String sql = "INSERT INTO KYC_RECORD ....";
int autoIncKeyFromApi = -1;

Connection connection = ....

try {     
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);    
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);    
    ps.setString( ... );    
    ps.executeUpdate();    
    rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();    
    if (rs.next()) {
        autoIncKeyFromApi = rs.getInt(1);
    } else {   
        // throw an exception from here
    }    
    connection.commit();
}
```

Comment: Yes.  JDBC connections are not thread safe.  The database behavior is controlled by the transaction manager.

Comment: The generated keys are local to each connection. Therefore it's thread-safe (assuming each thread has it's own `java.sql.Connection`)

Comment: The connections are coming from the container (Liferay Tomcat) pool. The pool does not give the same connection to two concurrently running threads even though the connections are reused across threads.

Answer (score 2):

The value of autoincrement of the column is managed on database level. Therefore you can fetch the value to `getGeneratedKeys()`  without worry in multithreaded environment.

The transaction is started as soon as you call the update SQL statement. It happens on database level. It stays open until you commit it manually or if autocommit is enabled.

If you need to get more info about transactions, see [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).